# How to update Multiple states in a batch using useState

Tags: reactjs, react-native

in a conventional react, inside the onChange function you would typically batch state updates like this

```
_onChange:function(){
this.setState({
    date: new Date(),
    setShowDatepicker: false()
})
```

}

I'm trying to figure out how to batch state updates in functional react

```
  const [date, setDate] = useState();
  const [showDatePicker, setShowDatepicker] = useState(false);

  const onChangeDate = (event, selectedDate) => {
     const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
     setDate(currentDate); //want to batch this will the setState below
     setShowDatepicker(false);
  };
```

Each time I set state it causes a re-render effecting the behaviour. Can't see the solution in the documentation. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's automatically batched, it won't trigger a re-render until the method has finished. What side effects are you getting?

Comment: When I comment out the setDate(currentDate) the picker closes as expected, but when its uncommented, the date gets set but the picker stays open/reopens

Comment: @IanVasco I had assumed it was a re-render that caused the picker to reopen or something, but if they're batched automatically the problem lays elsewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create put date and setShowDatePicker to the a single useState

```
const [dateValues, setDateValues] = useState({
    date: new Date(),
    setShowDatepicker: false
});

const onChangeDate = (event, selectedDate) => {
  const currentDate = selectedDate || date;

  setDateValues({
      date: currentDate,
      setShowDatepicker: false
  })
};
```

Comment: Although from the comment above saying that the render won't occur until the function has finished. This solution solved the problem. Without the datepicker re-opening. Not really sure where the issue is. Thanks!